# Python Dictionary key index issue (possibly scope?)

Tags: python, json, twitter, dictionary

I've run into a slightly strange issue when pulling text from the json response to querying the twitter API.

If I pull the text in this manner:

```
def retrieveText(raw_tweets):
    for l in raw_tweets:
       format_data = json.loads(l)

        for k in format_data.keys():
           if k == 'text':
               text = format_data['text']
```

I do not have any issues. However, it is a bit cumbersome to constantly iterate over the list of keys.

If I change to this version:

```
def retrieveText(raw_tweets):
    for l in raw_tweets:
        format_data = json.loads(l)
        text = format_data['text']
```

I receive a KeyError, which does not make sense to me based on the results of the previous code snippet.

If anyone has an insight on something I am overlooking, please let me know.

Comment: In your first block of code you are first testing if a key called 'text' exists, and if so you are extracting it, in your second block you are assuming that that key always exists.  Is it in every record?

Comment: The key 'text' does appear in every record (twitter documentation states it should anyway haha); however, it would seem I can only access it by checking to see it if exists first.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
for k in format_data.keys():
    if k == 'text':
        text = format_data['text']
```

Could be rewritten as:

```
if 'text' in format_data:
    text = format_data['text']
```

Comment: No. It *should* be `if 'text' in format_data:`. Doing `'text' in format_data.keys()` is `O(n)` while `'text' in format_data` is `O(1)`.